# Cannot create a model after the table renaming in Laravel project

Tags: php, pdo, laravel-6

I have a problem with creating a new model after the renaming table in the Laravel 6 project.

I run the migration which successfully renamed the `events` table to the `posts`.
After that, I renamed the `App\Event` model to `App\Post` and updated the `$table` attribute in this class to "posts". After these manipulations, I can see the list of the existing post, so the `select` commands run well.
But when I try to create a new model with `Post::create()` I got a strange error message:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.events' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `posts` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2021-10-21 13:57:30, 2021-10-21 13:57:30))
```

As you can see, the SQL query inserts data to the `posts` table, but the error is related to the `events`.

I thought the old table name is cached somewhere and cleaned cache in `bootstrap/cache`, `storage/framework/cache` and with all artisan commands. This does not help and I still have this issue.

Comment: Check for triggers in your database as well as any event triggers or boot code in Laravel.

Comment: You are right! Thank you, you saved my day :)! Please write the answer, I'll rate it!